# How can I use ngChange in ngRepeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-change

```js
angular.module('app',[]).controller('NgListController',function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
        {name:'Coke', price: 5, sum: 2, sumMoney: 10},
        {name:'Bread', price: 3, sum: 2, sumMoney: 6}
      ];
    $scope.priceChange = function(newVal, oldVal){
      //TODO
    };
});
```

```css
.sum{
  width:25px;
}
.sumMoney{
  width:40px;
  background-color:#EEE;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <fieldset ng-controller="NgListController">
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
          <p>
            <lable>{{item.name}},</lable>
            <lable>$ {{item.price}} x </lable> 
            <input type="text" class="sum" ng-model="item.sum" ng-change="priceChange(item.price)">
             = 
            <input type="text" class="sumMoney" ng-model="item.sumMoney" ng-readonly="true">
          </p>
        </div>
        <span>Totol money : {{totalMoney}}</span>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to use ng-repeat and ng-change in an angular-js app. check the snippet above. How can I get every item's sum money when its sum change and get the total money of all items?

Comment: you need to get the multiplied value by changing the numbers in the text field is this you need to achieve right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('NgListController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
    name: 'Coke',
    price: 5,
    sum: 2,
    sumMoney: 10
  }, {
    name: 'Bread',
    price: 3,
    sum: 2,
    sumMoney: 6
  }];


  $scope.oldObj = {};

  $scope.$watch('items', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    for (var k in newValue) {
      if (newValue.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        if (newValue[k].sum != oldValue[k].sum) {
          $scope.oldObj = newValue[k];
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    $scope.calPrice();
  }, true);


  $scope.totalMoney = 0;

  $scope.calPrice = function(html_code) {
    $scope.totalMoney = 0;
    $scope.items.forEach(function(value) {
      value.sumMoney = (value.price * value.sum);
      $scope.totalMoney += value.sumMoney;
    });
  }



});
```

```css
.sum {
  width: 25px;
}
.sumMoney {
  width: 40px;
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.7/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <fieldset ng-controller="NgListController">
    <div ng-repeat="(itemKey,item) in items">
      <p>
        <lable>{{item.name}},</lable>
        <lable>$ {{item.price}} x</lable>
        <input type="text" class="sum" ng-model="item.sum">=
        <input type="text" ng-model="item.sumMoney" class="sumMoney" ng-readonly="true">
      </p>
    </div>
    <span>Totol money : {{totalMoney}}</span>
    <br>
    <br>

    <br>
    <br>
    <span>Changed Value : {{oldObj}}</span>
  </fieldset>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can I get every sumMoney WITHOUT changing the `ng-model= sumMoney ` into `ng-value=" item.sum*item.price"` ?

Comment: you can watch the value of sum and update the sumMoney accordingley. do you want me to update my answer?

Comment: @SamSu updated the code according to your requirement.

Comment: ths for updating, and can I know which item has changed when using `$scope.watch` method ?

Answer (score 1):

> ### Use This Line :- input type="text" class="sum" ng-model="item.sum" ng-change="priceChange()"
>
> `$scope.items = [
>               {name: 'Coke', price: 5, sum: 2, sumMoney: 10},
>               {name: 'Bread', price: 3, sum: 2, sumMoney: 6}
>           ];
>           $scope.totalMoney = 0;
>           $scope.priceChange = function () {
>               var total = 0;
>               for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
>                   total = total + ($scope.items[i].price * $scope.items[i].sum);
>               }
>               $scope.totalMoney = total;
>           };
>           $scope.priceChange();`